# Dual monitor setup using onboard VGA and PCI VGA

Tags: motherboard, bios, vga, multiple-monitors, pci

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I use an onboard and pci vga simultaneously?](https://superuser.com/questions/44781/can-i-use-an-onboard-and-pci-vga-simultaneously)
>   [How can I enable onboard graphics AND dedicated card simultaneously?](https://superuser.com/questions/241157/how-can-i-enable-onboard-graphics-and-dedicated-card-simultaneously)

I recently added a video card to my computer using a PCI slot, I was hoping to be able to use a dual monitor setup using my built in VGA and my new card, but my motherboard seems to have disabled the onboard one. I was able to figure out how to switch between the two in the BIOS but not how to run them simultaneously. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you sure it is PCI and not PCIe?  What motherboard? What video card?

Comment: It's PCI , the motherboard is  Nagami-GL8E. I'm working on finding the video card model

Comment: the video card is GEForce FX 5500 OC

Comment: @JefNull from what I've been reading, you just can't do it with that motherboard (it's actually an Asus A8N-LA).  This (not being able to use both) is pretty usual on all but the most recent systems (see linked possible Dupes).